# Channel: communication between different cores

Tags: julia, channel

I would like to have a Channel between two functions running on two different cores. The following code does not work:

```
c1=Channel(32)   
@spawnat 2 put!(c1,1)
@spawnat 3 println(c1)
```

the println tells me that the channel c1 on core 3 is empty. I get no error. Somehow the function on core 3 sees a different channel c1 than core 2.

Answer (score 2):

`Channel` is for communication between co-routines (aka Green Threading).

For distributed computing normally you use `remotecall` - see this example from [Julia manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/parallel-computing/index.html):

```
$ ./julia -p 2

julia> r = remotecall(rand, 2, 2, 2)
Future(2, 1, 4, nothing)

julia> s = @spawnat 2 1 .+ fetch(r)
Future(2, 1, 5, nothing)

julia> fetch(s)
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.18526  1.50912
 1.16296  1.60607
```

Depending on your actual scenario you should have a look at the following libraries for distributed computing with Julia:

- [SharedArrays](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.1/stdlib/SharedArrays/) - shared memory across processed on the same host
- [DistributedArrays.jl](https://github.com/JuliaParallel/DistributedArrays.jl) - shared data across different processes on different hosts
- [ParallelDataTransfer.jl](https://github.com/ChrisRackauckas/ParallelDataTransfer.jl) - sending the data between processes.

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
const c1=RemoteChannel(()->Channel{Int}(32));
@spawnat 2 put!(c1,1)
@spawnat 3 println(take!(c1))
```

[Found here](https://codingclubuc3m.rbind.io/post/2018-06-06/)